# python ElementTree XML iteration

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file structured like so:

```
<fcd-export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/fcd_file.xsd">
<timestep time="28800.00">
</timestep>
<timestep time="28801.00">
    <vehicle id="301614_485_0" x="13944.12" y="13808.84" angle="276.89" type="pkw" speed="0.00" pos="4.40" lane="23914010#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
</timestep>
<timestep time="28802.00">
    <vehicle id="301614_485_0" x="13942.45" y="13809.04" angle="276.89" type="pkw" speed="2.01" pos="6.41" lane="23914010#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
</timestep>
<timestep time="28803.00">
    <vehicle id="302675_485_0" x="14013.72" y="12670.03" angle="172.02" type="pkw" speed="0.00" pos="4.40" lane="51827455#5_0" slope="0.00"/>
    <vehicle id="301614_485_0" x="13939.51" y="13809.40" angle="276.89" type="pkw" speed="3.55" pos="9.96" lane="23914010#0_0" slope="0.00"/>
</timestep> ...
```

I have to create timestep objects with a list of vehicles inside:

```
traces = [] # list with traces
tree = ET.parse(traceFile)
root = tree.getroot()
timeID = 0
for second in root.iter('timestep'):
    traces.append(Time(float(second.get('time'))))
    if not second:
        print("timestep empty")
    else:
        for car in second.iter('vehicle'):
            traces[timeID].cars.append(Car(car.get('id'), float(car.get('x')), float(car.get('y'))))
    timeID += 1
return traces
```

But that isn't working. After creating a timestep object, it's iterating through the whole file, instead of just the vehicles inside it.

Time and Car are classes I created

```
class Car:
def __init__(self, id, x, y):
    self.id = id
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class Time:
def __init__(self, sec):
    self.sec = sec
cars = []
def countCars(self):
    return len(self.cars)
```

Comment: What's your desired output given your sample xml?

Comment: I need, among other things, to count how many cars are present in each timestep

Comment: You say that it's iterating through the whole file - can you post your `traces` output showing this? Ideally for a cut down version of your file (such as the one in your question).

Comment: print (traces):
[<__main__.Time object at 0x1067c9e80>, <__main__.Time object at 0x116cf0eb0>, <__main__.Time object at 0x116cf0df0>, <__main__.Time object at 0x116cf0c10>]

Comment: print (Time.cars):
[<__main__.Car object at 0x116cf0e50>, <__main__.Car object at 0x116cf0d30>, <__main__.Car object at 0x116cf0b50>, <__main__.Car object at 0x116cf0bb0>]


Equal for all 4 Time objects

Comment: " count how many cars are present in each timestep" - so, focusing on this, in your xml, the output would be `0, 1, 1, 2`?

Comment: Yes, but it's 4, 4, 4, 4.

Comment: I only see 4 vehicle ids in your xml and 4 timesteps, with the first having no vehicles. Where do you get 16 vehicles?

Comment: It is appending all 4 vehicles of the xml for each timestep, instead of appending just the vehicles inside each timestep tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `cars` arttribute of your `Time` class is connected to the class itself, rather than an instance of the class. As such, all of your `Time` classes share the same `cars` list, and append to and present this same list.

If you move your `cars = []` instantiation inside your `__init__()` function, and change it to `self.cars = []`, it should resolve your issue.

```py
class Time:
    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec
        self.cars = []

    def countCars(self):
        return len(self.cars)
```